# Automatic report generation

Tags: input, automation, resume

I am trying to automatically create a curriculum vitae (or any other document if one would prefer) from a `datafile` that holds all values/entries.

Here are my individual files that go into this project:

CV.tex reads in CV_data.tex and uses CV_formats.tex to create a curriculum vitae in this case. All three files must be in the same directory and one must run CV.tex to invoke the other two and build the final document.

**The resume class I am using can be found [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/res.cls)**

**CV.tex**

```
\input{CV_formats}

\begin{document}
\input{CV_data}
\end{document}
%% eof
```

**CV_formats.tex**

```
\documentclass{res}
%
% \usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in,]{geometry}
% \usepackage{res}
%
\usepackage{ifthen}              %% if-then-else arguments
\usepackage{paralist,array}      %% enhancements to array environment
\usepackage{float,multirow,longtable}  %% multipage tables, multirow cells
\usepackage{lscape,rotating}     %% allows for landscape tables and figures
\usepackage{color,url}           %% allows for colors and easy formatting of URL's
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}     %% AMS math macros; esp. \text{} in math environment 
%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\newsectionwidth{0pt}  % So the text is not indented under section headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % use this package to get a 2 line header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % suppress line drawn by default by fancyhdr
\setlength{\headheight}{22pt} % allow room for 2-line header
\setlength{\headsep}{24pt}  % space between header and text
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt} % allow room for 2-line header
\pagestyle{fancy}     % set pagestyle for document
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\rhead{ {\it My.Name.GoesHere}\\{\it p. \thepage} } % put text in header (right side)
\cfoot{}                                     % the foot is empty
\topmargin=-0.5in % start text higher on the page

%% =============================================================================
\def\output#1{\def\outp@t{#1}}   %% output format specifier  
%% --- SET OUTPUT FORMAT ----- 
\output{CV}  
%% =============================================================================
%
%% =========================================
%% definition of data names
\def\name#1{\def\n@me{#1}}
\def\raddress#1{\def\r@ddress{#1}}
\def\waddress#1{\def\w@ddress{#1}}
\def\educationa#1{\def\educ@tiona{#1}}
\def\educationb#1{\def\educ@tionb{#1}}
\def\educationc#1{\def\educ@tionc{#1}}

\def\institutea#1{\def\in@titutea{#1}}
\def\instituteb#1{\def\in@tituteb{#1}}
\def\institutec#1{\def\in@titutec{#1}}
% 
% \def\gpa1#1{\def\gp@1{#1}}
% \def\gpa2#1{\def\gp@2{#1}}
% \def\gpa3#1{\def\gp@3{#1}}

\def\dissertationa#1{\def\dissert@tiona{#1}}
\def\dissertationb#1{\def\dissert@tionb{#1}}
\def\dissertationc#1{\def\dissert@tionc{#1}}

\def\skillsa#1{\def\skill@a{#1}}
\def\skillsb#1{\def\skill@b{#1}}
\def\skillsc#1{\def\skill@c{#1}}

% \def\sponsornote#1{\def\spons@rnote{#1}}
% \def\status#1{\def\st@tus{#1}}
% \def\investigator#1{\def\investig@tor{#1}}
% \def\CoI#1{\def\Co@I{#1}}
% \def\location#1{\def\loc@tion{#1}}
% \def\note#1{\def\n@te{#1}}
%%% initialize data names
  \name{}
  \raddress{}
  \waddress{}
  \educationa{}
  \educationb{}
  \educationc{}
  \institutea{}
  \instituteb{}
  \institutec{}
%   \gpa1{}
%   \gpa2{}
%   \gpa3{}
  \dissertationa{}
  \dissertationb{}
  \dissertationc{}
  \skillsa{}
  \skillsb{}
  \skillsc{}
%% ------------------------------------------

%%%
\newcommand{\ms}{\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}}
\newcommand{\ws}{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{5ex}}
%% ==========================================
%% CV format for table descriptions
%\newcommand{\FormFperiod}{Performance Period: }
%% -------------------------------------
\begin{resume}
 \newcommand{\CVentry}{

\thispagestyle{empty} % this page has no header  
\name{\n@me\\ [12pt]  }% the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name

\address{{\bf \w@ddress}}      

\address{{\bf \r@ddress}}


\vspace{0.2in}
\section{\centerline{EDUCATION}} 
\vspace{8pt}

{\sl \textbf{\educ@tiona, \in@titutea}}\\
\textbf{\dissert@tiona} \\
{Skills:} \skill@a

{\sl \textbf{\educ@tionb}}\\
\textbf{\dissert@tionb} \\
{Skills:} \skill@b

{\sl \textbf{\educ@tionc}}\\
\textbf{\dissert@tionc} \\
{Skills:} \skill@c



  %% reset variables
  \name{}
  \raddress{}
  \waddress{}
  \educationa{}
  \educationb{}
  \educationc{}
  \institutea{}
  \instituteb{}
  \institutec{}
%   \gpa1{}
%   \gpa2{}
%   \gpa3{}
  \dissertationa{}
  \dissertationb{}
  \dissertationc{}
  \skillsa{}
  \skillsb{}
  \skillsc{}


}
\end{resume}




\ifthenelse{\equal{\outp@t}{CV}}{% true condition 
  \def\entry{\CVentry}
  }{}% leave false condition blank    



%% eof
```

**CV_data.tex**

```
%% ==========================================
  \name{My.Name}
  \raddress{Res address}
  \waddress{Work address}
  \educationa{PhD}
  \educationb{MS}
  \educationc{BE}
  \institutea{MTU}
  \instituteb{MTU}
  \institutec{VTU}
%   \gpa1{}
%   \gpa2{}
%   \gpa3{}
  \dissertationa{P1}
  \dissertationb{P2}
  \dissertationc{P3}
  \skillsa{s1}
  \skillsb{s2}
  \skillsc{s3}
%   \entry

%% end data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

When I run **CV.tex** it doesn't seem to generate my full document and skips all the "address", "education", "institute", "dissertation" details.

What am I missing in the implementation?
This was built on a previous colleague's implementation and he is unavailable to ask! `:(`

Comment: Side comment: you might be interested in [Peter Flynn's ideas about using LaTeX in conjunction with XML](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/flynn/flynn.pdf).

Comment: Why you use `\def\dissertationa#1{\def\dissert@tiona{#1}}` instead of `\newcommand` ? I have created similar documents sucesfuly using `\newcommand`

Comment: Your datafile isn't doing anything, it only stores informations. Try what happens if you uncomment the line with `\entry`.

Comment: With `\entry` it didn't make any difference! Will try a few more things. I wonder if it is because of the res class wreaking havoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main errors in your files:

1. In `CV_formats.tex`, remove the `\begin{resume}` and `\end{resume}`. You can't  use an environment (which on top you haven't defined) before `\begin{document}`,
2. Resumes are typeset by the `\CVentry` command. Add that command after `\input{CV_data}` in `CV.tex`, and
3. As you are using the `@` character as part of command names in `CV_formats.tex`, you need to write `\makeatletter` before the first line using `@` (i.e., `\def\output#1{\def\outp@t{#1}}`) and add `\makeatother` at the end of the file.

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand what 2) that you suggest means. "Add that command after \input{CV_data} in CV.tex, and"... What is `that` command?

Comment: @drN `\CVentry`, the command mentioned in the previous sentence

Comment: would you mind sharing what you did?

Comment: @drN I did exactly what I wrote in my answer. I've uploaded the files [here](http://ge.tt/1AFabQi?c) for you.